# UIPageViewController conditionally Go to the next page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I've `UIPageViewController` and I can go next and previous page using below delegate methods.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[PageController class]])
       return nil;

    if(_counter < 1) {
       return nil;
    }

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"memoTable"];
}
```

**Edit:**

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    //NSLog(@"Child controller count  = %lu",(unsigned long)pageViewController.childViewControllers.count);

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[PageController class]])
        return nil;

    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[TableViewController class]])
    {
        TableViewController *viewController1 = (TableViewController*) viewController;
        if (viewController1.dataArr.count < 5) {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageView"];
}
```

Now I want to go next page if some condition satisfied. Like last page **viewController.isCheck == true**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: hmm, i'm a bit uncertain though with your question. What do you mean by last page viewController? How do you retrieve the last page viewController?

Comment: delegate method always call when you swipe the page view controller, In this you check the condition, if condition true then you should load the new view controller.

Comment: @SaurabhJain I am checking in `viewControllerAfterViewController `. Its working fine. But facing one problm that if `viewControllerAfterViewController` return nil then next time I am unable to swipe page.

Comment: @SaurabhJain Got my issue?

Comment: @EktaPadaliya return nil i.e. your view controller is the last view controller.

Comment: @SaurabhJain yes. when `viewControllerAfterViewController ` returns nil after I am unable to swipe and 'viewControllerAfterViewController' never call.

Comment: @SaurabhJain Got my problem ? Please help me.

Comment: @EktaPadaliya have you got any exception message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126513/discussion-between-ekta-padaliya-and-saurabh-jain).

Answer (score 0):

You can just add that condition to one of the existing ifs and return nil if the condition isn't verified. Something like:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[PageController class]] || ((YourViewControllerClass *)viewController).isCheck == false)
       return nil;

    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageView"];
}
```

Comment: I did same like you but If it returns nil then next time it will not allow to scroll even if the condition satisfied.

Comment: Have you made the cast to your ViewController subclass?

Comment: My issue is that when above method return nil after that I am unable to swipe. i.e after nil above method never call.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the view controller you instantiated before returning it in `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController` method.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[PageController class]])
       return nil;

    let pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageView"];
    if (pageViewController.isCheck)
       return pageViewController;
    else return nil;
}
```

Comment: I did same like you but If it returns nil then next time it will not allow to scroll even if the condition satisfied.

Comment: Have you made the cast to your ViewController subclass?

Comment: How do you make the condition satisfied? If it is when the view controller is being instantiated then the code will work, but if it is outside instantiation then you need to store the view controller because instantiation will just make a new instance that might not contains your satisfied condition.

Comment: @ramacode I want to add only one viewController and repeat it to when user swipe. Like when user swipe I have one viewController not different.

Answer (score 0):

My second guess is that you should try to instantiate all the view controllers that you will need in the `UIPageViewController` before you navigate.

```
UIViewController* memoViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"memoTable"];
UIViewController* pageViewContentController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageView"];
```

assign all the view controllers you will need in an array

```
NSArray* reservedViewControllers = @[memoViewController, pageViewController];
```

use index to track where you current page is

```
int currentIndex = 0;
```

Then you can easily iterate between your view controllers in the UIPageViewControllerDataSource functions.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
        if(currentIndex == 0) return nil;
        currentIndex = currentIndex - 1;
        return reservedViewControllers[currentIndex];
    }

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(currentIndex == reservedViewControllers.count) return nil;
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    //check for last page
    if(currentIndex == reservedViewControllers.count){
          UIViewController* lastViewController = reservedViewControllers[currentIndex];
          if(lastViewController.isCheck == false) return nil;
    }

    return reservedViewControllers[currentIndex];
}
```

Comment: I want to add only one viewController and repeat it to when user swipe. Like when user swipe I have one viewController not different.

Comment: @ramcode I want to add "memoTable" whenever user swipe. 
I need to add "memoTable" whenever user swipe to next and condition satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you should use the scroll view for this purpose.. set the content size of the scroll view and give the content offset to the content on your table... 
for your reference:

see the link:
https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers
https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView